# When deep cloning an object, should string be deepcloned as well? Goal is for caching

Tags: c#, caching

Let's say I have an object like so:

```
public class MyObject
{
    string MyString {get;set;}

    public MyObject DeepCopy()
    {
        return new MyObject { MyString = ??? } // string.copy(MyString), or MyString ?
    }
}
```

The goal is to cache this object (`IMemoryCache`). Is it safe to use `MyString = MyString`? Or will it's reference point to unallocated memory when the scope of MyObject will end?

I am wondering, as the string itself is immutable, so if the reference stays valid, it seems like a good idea to not copy each character (`string.copy`), which might be costly for nothing.

Comment: There's no need to make a copy of the string as it is immutable.

Comment: [`String.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.copy?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) is obsolete already

Comment: It's not entirely clear which question in your post you're meaning to ask. As far as whether the reference will remain valid, see first marked duplicate. It is fundamental to GC-based systems that references (except explicitly weak ones) will _always_ be valid. An object is only collected when it becomes unreachable; if you have a reference to it you can access, _it's not unreachable_. As far as whether copying the string reference is safe in cloning, of course it is. The object's state can never change, so there's never a reason to make a copy of it. Just use the original object.